# How to transform given latitude and longitude data to map frame

Tags: ros, localization, gps, transforms, gnss

I am working with a multi sensor RTK-GNSS for localization of my robot.

This is the data I am getting from the GNSS system.

[image]

How to relate this data to my robot map frame for navigation?

Comment: I see relative position in meters right there- does the interface allow you to set  the origin of the relative position to your current location or any coordinates?  Otherwise are you wanting a method to convert latitude/longitude/altitude to distance relative to a reference point of your choosing in code?  I left a comment on https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24117/gps-to-cartesian#comment39021_24117 which could be helpful, if you are interested in that I'll expand it out into a full answer using python and geopy

Comment: You must use UTM coordinates. Read this answer here: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/24124/7097 and take a look to this python package [here](https://pypi.org/project/utm/). Basically you need to define a point on your map using the UTM coordinates. Then you get a GNSS position, convert it to UTM and use conventional math calculation to find out the position on your map